# Typescript generics: map with keys of type T[K] to values of T itself (grouping T[] by own property value)

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I wanted to write a generic function that can create a map of objects where the keys are properties of the objects themselves, as such grouping them by values of one of their properties.

I ended up writing the following code:

```js
type PartialRecord<K extends keyof any, T> = {
  [P in K]?: T;
};

const innerMap = <T, K extends keyof any>(
  array: T[], customKey: keyof T
): PartialRecord<K, T> => {
    const innerMap: PartialRecord<K, T> = {};
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
      innerMap[array[i][customKey] as K] = array[i];
    }
    return innerMap;
  }
}
```

It gives the error: `Conversion of type 'T[keyof T]' to type 'K' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first`.

So you would get: `innerMap[array[i][customKey] as unknown as K`, which (doubly) defeats the purpose of typing.

What it should do is this:

```js
export class CuteKitty {
  constructor(readonly furColor: string, readonly eyeColor: string) {}
}
const redKittyBlueEyes = new CuteKitty('red', 'blue');
const redKittyRedEyes = new CuteKitty('red', 'red');
const whiteKittyRedEyes = new CuteKitty('white', 'red');

const furColorMap = innerMap([redKittyBlueEyes, redKittyRedEyes, whiteKittyRedEyes], 'furColor');
// Result: {
//   red: [redKittyBlueEyes, redKittyRedEyes];
//   white: [whiteKittyRedEyes];
// }

const eyeColorMap = innerMap([redKittyBlueEyes, redKittyRedEyes, whiteKittyRedEyes], 'eyeColor');
// Result: {
//   blue: [redKittyBlueEyes];
//   red: [redKittyRedEyes, whiteKittyRedEyes];
// }
```

Without casting `innerMap[array[i][customKey]] as unknown as K`, how can I ensure that `array[i][customKey]` is a type that can be used for indexing (specifically the type I substitute for `K`)?

Comment: This is pretty hard to follow. Can you post some usage example of `createInnerMap`? And maybe explain more what the purpose of this code is?

Comment: @Alex Wayne Hello, I took your advice and changed it with more clear code and examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Learned some stuff along the way, so I adjusted my answer several times. Final solution is the most useful imo.

### 1. Original Answer

Found a solution without having to use the dirty fix of casting "as unknown as K".

I made these custom types:

```
type TRecordKey = string | number | symbol;
type TRecurringRecord<K extends T[keyof T] & TRecordKey, T> = {
  [P in K]?: T
}
```

Then I adjusted the above code like this:

```
const recurringMap<K extends T[keyof T] & TRecordKey, T>(
  array: T[],
  customKey: keyof T
): TRecurringRecord<K, T> {
  const recurringMap: TRecurringRecord<K, T> = {};
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
    recurringMap[array[i][customKey] as K] = array[i];
  }
  return recurringMap;
}
```

Now you can throw in an array of objects, and the string name of a property, and it will group those objects by that property in a map.

### 2. Answer 03-10-2022

Wrote simpler code for basically the same thing.

- Removed `TRecordKey` and `TRecurringRecord` with an Indexable type, which just states that keys should be strings. This is a much simpler way to take care of the "neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other" warning. (doesn't work if your object has number/symbol properties).
- No more need to cast "as K".
- Map to arrays of type T instead of only 1 instance.

```js
type TIndexable = {
   [key: string]: any;
};

const mapFromProperty = <T extends TIndexable>(
  objects: T[], propertyName: keyof T
): Record<string, T[]> => {
  return objects.reduce((accumulator: Record<string, T[]>, current: T): Record<string, T[]> => {
    if (!accumulator[current[propertyName]]) {
      accumulator[current[propertyName]] = [current];
    } else {
      accumulator[current[propertyName]].push(current);
    }
    return accumulator;
  }, {});
}
```

### 3. Answer 01-08-2023

- Fixed inferred type of the function's result (key should be `T[K]` not `K`).
- Re-added and improved strong typing for `K`, since personally I usually only want keys to be of type `number | string | symbol` and not an object.
- Removed the `TIndexable` type, just using `Record<any, any>` instead which will allow any object.

```js
type TRecordKey = string | number | symbol;

// Mapping to 1 instance of T in case of unique keys
const recurringMapSingle = <
    K extends (T[K] extends Record<any, any> ? never : (keyof T & TRecordKey)),
    T extends Record<any, any>
  >(objects: T[], key: K): Partial<Record<T[K], T>> => {
    return objects.reduce((acc: Partial<Record<T[K], T>>, x: T) => {
        acc[x[key]] = x;
        return acc;
    }, {});
}

// Mapping to multiple instances of T
const recurringMapMultiple = <
    K extends (T[K] extends Record<any, any> ? never : (keyof T & TRecordKey)),
    T extends Record<any, any>
  >(objects: T[], key: K): Partial<Record<T[K], T[]>> => {
    return objects.reduce((acc: Partial<Record<T[K], T[]>>, x: T) => {
        if (acc[x[key]]) {
          acc[x[key]].push(x);
        } else {
          acc[x[key]] = [x];
        }
        return acc;
    }, {});
}
```

`T[K] extends Record<any, any> ? never : (keyof T & TRecordKey)` means that if the type of the property at key `K` is an object, that can `never` be the case, so it generates an error when you try to pass the name of a property of that type into the function. Otherwise, `K` must be a key of `T` and must also be either a `string`, `number` or `symbol`.