# Typescript generic type: map list of records by it's nested attribute

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I'm writing a custom type called "RecordsByType", left as unknown in the following snippet.

I have types that represent database records and each record has its type defined in a nested attribute ["attributes"]["type"], see Account for example. Unfortunately, this is the only thing in the snipped that cannot be changed.
Ofc there will be many more "RecordTypes" than just Account or User.

```js
type RecordTypeName = 'Account' | 'User';
type RecordType = Account | User;
type RecordKey = keyof DbRecord | keyof Account | keyof User;

interface DbRecord {
    attributes: {
        type: RecordTypeName;
    };
}

interface Account extends DbRecord {
    attributes: {
        type: 'Account';
    };
    name: string;
}

interface User extends DbRecord {
    attributes: {
        type: 'User';
    };
    email: string;
}

const account1: Account = { attributes: { type: 'Account' }, name: 'A1' };
const account2: Account = { attributes: { type: 'Account' }, name: 'A2' };
const user: User = { attributes: { type: 'User' }, email: 'email@email.com' };

type RecordsByType = unknown;

// Next line is initialised with some values to show what the type should look like, 
// but we should be able to initialise it without any values as well,  
// i.e. just '= {};' should work too.
const recordsByType: RecordsByType = {
    Account: [account1, account2],
    User: [user]
};

// Next line should compile. Should be Account[] and not generic DbRecord[] nor RecordType[].
const accounts: Account[] = recordsByType['Account'] || [];

// Next line should not compile as user is not type of Account.
recordsByType['Account']?.push(user);
```

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62663895/typescript-generics-map-with-keys-of-type-tk-to-values-of-t-itself-grouping) seems a lot related, but my key "attribute" is nested and does not have to be this generic.

**1. attempt**
First I tried this type, but the problem is that the value of "type" does not match the list of records, so the result will always be incorrectly the generic DbRecord[].

```js
type RecordsByType = Partial<Record<DbRecord['attributes']['type'], DbRecord[]>>;
// => Type DbRecord[] is not assignable to type Account[]
```

**2. attempt**
So I tried to match the "type" value with the value in the record, but again similar issue.

```js
type RecordsByType<
    T extends K['attributes']['type'],
    K extends RecordType
> = Partial<Record<T, K[]>>;
// Next line would not compile as the result is RecordType[] and not Account[]
const accounts: Account[] = recordsByType['Account'] || [];
```

**Thoughts**
I need to somehow define that each record's ["attributes"]["type"] value matches the "key" value and somehow be able to return a list of specific implementations per each key instead of the generic type.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the missing attributes, I removed them from the question as they are not relevant. The thing is I can't just remove the annotation as I need to have the ability to initialise the `recordsByType` as empty object/map and then add/read from it dynamically. I have updated the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this, you'll want to start with a union of the possible types (`Acccount`, `User`, etc.):

```
type AllTypes = Account | User /* | SomethingElse | AnotherThing etc. */;
```

Then we can define `RecordsByType` as a mapped type mapping the `type` property types as keys to arrays of the relevant type, which we get by extracting anything assignable to `{ attributes: { type: Key } }` from `AllTypes`:

```
type RecordsByType = {
    [Key in AllTypes["attributes"]["type"]]?: Extract<AllTypes, { attributes: { type: Key } }>[];
};
```

Then this compiles as desired:

```
const accounts: Account[] = recordsByType["Account"] || [];
```

...and this fails as desired:

```
recordsByType["Account"]?.push(user);
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAShDGB7ATgEwCrggOQIYFtoBeKAIgEF4kBXAO2FKgB8yBVAZwmVIG4AoUJFgIUGLFBKUa9ZlA5d+g6HCRoA0hBASoAa02IAZlAAiAIxWjZekIahTEdYFf1H5yfnwCW9LgdzxoMws0KABvPihIqFxgYGRPU2pgCHYALjCIqKyldOCxSDxCfiyAX34Svi8fZD8AuyoHGQgAD2TaVHYTcxEQ8KyYuISklPS+rKicsntHXkzIsrmoWgIIdPZB2gBzcsrvZJr-aDcoFraOrryM-tj4xOS0q-HIydI3WdLiqIh8XE8AGzWG22fAqfCQtHW0QajgAjOlpjISGNIgNbsMHqEoC8EQwoCUADSLZaEdIUGGkQkLcGQ-zSYAAJnh0MRjxRNyG91GWKwpJxjAJRJWvPpFJB-GpTmonGQ6WOSMWqI5IzC3MgpLeeMJWW+vwBZB1-wAAga-gA6JD4UULATich-P6YSCdSTMpwsY4AegAVLIAMqIQjAAAW3k2AFE-pxZORaIhg1x0CGtidgPBTVAvR6PEphKoOgAhECO4isqAAbQ0Wm8dntxfYZdIiruKVIAF0G0o262APzpMOtZD+YAAHjtDqw7HxKqb6K5k0reLxAD4y63yh4JVBkD0C0WebnROxC8XtMj6nT0mXaY1gDCp9fHPTW1qom5L1KuM+xZUPR6oInPE6C0wH+FJok6VAUk8bdUDBRAIScB96AeHFV20bc8yPPdIAbPlW2YFhVw8X9-xDTo-H+TpcAgqCYKnUwEFwD8oAAAw-ZAWKgQDaAAckQ2hWJxFi+Aww9jywXDXTbbtTTAKUgwACnYgBKHggA)

---

*(FWIW, in modern code I'd use nullish coalescing [`??`] over logical OR [`||`] in `recordsByType["Account"] || []`, now that we have it: `recordsByType["Account"] ?? []`)*

Comment: Works great, even in use cases I did not mention in the question. Thanks!